# find and replace all the ? and =by / htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

hey all i am new to htaccess and i need to find and replace all the occurence of ? and = by / from the url by htacess

in my htaccess file the code is

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
 ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
 Options -Indexes 
 RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.domain.com [L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]


   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

there are some pages on the site like page2.php?id=34
currently it is showing like page2?id=34 but i want it like page2/id/34 and same for all the other pages

Comment: I'm pretty sure by doing that you are going to clobber your `$_GET` variables.

Comment: ohh. yes... is there any other way of doing this and still do not disturb $_GET

Answer (score 1):

You have everything you need already in your htaccess almost. You direct everything except files and directories that do not exist to page.php

Then in your PHP you rewrite urls like /page.php/id/2 to what you want.

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule . /page.php$1 [L,QSA]
```

You then just need to parse these url's in PHP inside page.php or index.php as many people use.

```
<?php
  $request  = str_replace("/page.php", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $params     = split("/", $request);
?>
```

Further reading on the idea of pretty urls here: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/ and http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Answer (score 1):

You can have:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.domain.com [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

### rules to convert ?n1=v1&n2=v2 /n1/v1/n2/v2 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page2\.php\? [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]+)&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1/%2 [DPI,E=QS:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_QS} =1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1/%2 [DPI,E=QS:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_QS} =1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^&=]+$
RewriteRule ^(page2)\.php$ /$1/%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,NE,R=302]

# recursion rule to replace /n1/v1/n2/v2 to QUERY_STRING
RewriteRule ^(page2)(?:\.php)?/([^/]+)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1.php$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA]

### end of convert ?n1=v1&n2=v2 /n1/v1/n2/v2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i am sorry but it had no effect on page2.php?id=2 almost same as before . no updates

Comment: This is properly tested and working rule on my Apache.

Comment: i have checked it dosent redirect page2.php?id=2 to page2/id/2

Comment: I have posted after thorough testing on my Apache and everything worked for that URL.

Comment: To test is better you should remove all other rules except the ones between `###` lines.